# Returning an array from the JavaScript OS.File.DirectoryIterator

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I am starting do some scripting using OS.File.DirectoryIterator from the OS.File module.  I've gotten the following block of code working...sort of.

What I'm trying to do is iterate through the given directory (which has 4 sub-directories) and place the names of the sub-directories into an array.  The hang-up is that the array is populated as expected but is not available outside of the promise construct.

Admittedly, I'm inexperienced with promises, so I'm sure the problem lies in how I've constructed this (which is lifted from the MDN page on OS.File.DirectoryIterator). So my question: why is the array accessible within the promise but not outside it?

```
var iterator = new OS.File.DirectoryIterator(PathToDir);
var subDirNames = [];

var promise = iterator.forEach(
   function(entry) {
      subDirNames.push(entry.name);
   }
);

promise.then(
   function(success) {
      iterator.close();
      console.log("--> "+subDirNames[1]); \\Array element 1 display in console fine.
      return subDirNames;
   },
   function(failure) {
      console.log("--> Error: "+failure);
   }
);
console.log("--> "+subDirNames[1]); \\Array element 1 displays as undefined.
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of special cases the concurrency model in JavaScript is the following:

- Code always runs from the first line to the last line synchronously. Things happen one by one.
- Everything that touches I/O (like file system or web access) returns immediately and instead reports completion alternatively - either by taking a callback or returning a promise.
- Unwrapping a promise is done in a different scope.

So, in a line *you can't* access `subDirNames` synchronously like you did since the I/O was not performed yet, instead you can detect when the I/O was completed by a promise. Luckily this is a for a generator add-on so you have alternative options for that too.

### Straight up promises approach

Chain the promise:

```
var p2 = promise.then(... /* your iterator.close() code here */); // new promise
//... run more code
// when you need to access subDirNames
p2.then(Function(names){
    console.log(names[1]); // will always work. 
});
```

This is the concurrency model - it's very useful and it avoids a lot of issues of threading.

#### Generators

Since you're developing something for Firefox directly you have no browser compatibility issues and can use the available features of EcmaScript 6. We can use generators which allow us to pause execution of a function and wait for results - first a little helper:

```
function async(gen){ "use strict"; // this takes a generator
    gen = gen(); // starts it
    return Promise.resolve().then(function cont(a){
        var n = gen.next(a); // gets the next element
        if(n.done) return Promise.resolve(n.value); // a `return` 
        if(!n.value.then) return cont(n.value); // yield plain value
        return n.value.catch(gen.throw.bind(gen)).then(cont);
    });
}
```

You can get this feature from libraries like [bluebird](/questions/tagged/bluebird) instead of you'd like (they do it faster, but that's not really relevant here).

This would let you do something like:

```
async(function*(){
    var iterator = new OS.File.DirectoryIterator(PathToDir);
    // optimally you'd do yield* iterator but this API predates modern iterators
    var subDirNames = [];
    yield iterator.forEach(function(entry) { // note the yield
        subDirNames.push(entry.name);
    });
    iterator.close();
    console.log(subDirNames[1]); // will log correctly
});
```

Comment: @benjamin -  Thanks for the detailed explanation and examples.  That cleared up a few things for me.  I was able to use your examples to do what I needed.  However, this brought up one more question...

In your chain example, does p2.then actually execute the promise each time it is called?  In other words, if I call p2.then every time I need to do something with array subDirNames, is another iteration of the directory being executed?

Comment: @user3402292 feel free to ask as many questions as you'd like in StackOverflow. It's best to keep it one question per thread so you'd probably want to open a new question. If you feel this one is answered consider [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)